# NodeJS: Async / Await Raspberry Pi

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, raspberry-pi, async-await, raspberry-pi3

I have some code that works perfectly on my day-to-day computer but that gives me an error when trying to launch from a raspberry pi (3 model B). The error goes like:

```
>     setInterval(async function () {
>                 ^^^^^
>     
>     SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
>         at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
>         at Module._compile (module.js:414:25)
>         at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
>         at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>         at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
>         at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
>         at startup (node.js:134:18)
>         at node.js:961:3
```

And my code is a 'simple' setInterval (1500 ms) with a async / await in it:

```
setInterval(async function () {

  var data = await foo();
        var obj = new mongooseModel({
          mk: data.mk,
          name: data.name,
          a: data.a,
          b: data.b,
          c: data.c,
          v: data.v,
          p: data.p,
          l: data.l,
          h: data.h,
          o: data.o,
          sn: data.sn,
          n: data.n,
        });
        obj.save(function(err, tick) {
          if (err) return console.log(err);
        });
      });
}, 1500);
```

anyone else has ever had this problem? 
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`async/await` supported by node.js starting from v7.6. You need to upgrade installed node.js version or use Promises.

Comment: Indeed! My version is v4.2.1 I used apt-get and thought I will get the latest version... let me install and come back to you! Thanks Alexmac

Comment: Depending on what OS you run, it might be easier to work with a node version manager like [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n).

Comment: Yeah, either way some kind of node version manager will probably be helpful. I've personally had issues dealing with the default Linux packages with node and NVM/n/whatever solves a lot of that.